# Channel creation fails in Hyperledger Fabric v1.2

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

I'm trying to start an [Hyperledger Fabric](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric) network in v1.2 with a network generated by myself (with binary `configtxgen`). The network starts correctly and no component indicates an error.

**However, when I try to create a new channel, an error occurs at the orderer level (one of the following three errors) and no channel is created.**

```
Orderer Server Status Code: (400) BAD_REQUEST. Description: error authorizing update: error validating ReadSet: existing config does not contain element for [Group]  /Channel/Application/Org1MSP but was in the read set
```

or

```
Orderer Server Status Code: (400) BAD_REQUEST. Description: error authorizing update: error validating ReadSet: existing config does not contain element for [Group]  /Channel/Application but was in the read set
```

or

```
Orderer Server Status Code: (400) BAD_REQUEST. Description: error authorizing update: error validating ReadSet: existing config does not contain element for [Value]  /Channel/Consortium but was in the read set
```

To create the channel, I use the Go SDK on the master branch and follow the same procedure as for functional tests.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Detailed orderer logs

```
2018-07-30 07:54:34.988 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 0c0 0xc42017c0b8 principal evaluation succeeds for identity 0
2018-07-30 07:54:34.988 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 0c1 0xc42017c0b8 gate 1532937274988361380 evaluation succeeds
2018-07-30 07:54:34.988 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 0c2 Signature set satisfies policy /Channel/Orderer/OrdererMSP/Writers
2018-07-30 07:54:34.988 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 0c3 == Done Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Orderer/OrdererMSP/Writers
2018-07-30 07:54:34.988 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 0c4 Signature set satisfies policy /Channel/Orderer/Writers
2018-07-30 07:54:34.988 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 0c5 == Done Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Orderer/Writers
2018-07-30 07:54:34.988 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 0c6 Signature set satisfies policy /Channel/Writers
2018-07-30 07:54:34.988 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 0c7 == Done Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Writers
2018-07-30 07:54:34.989 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 0c8 Adding to config map: [Group]  /Channel
2018-07-30 07:54:34.989 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 0c9 Adding to config map: [Group]  /Channel/Application
2018-07-30 07:54:34.989 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 0ca Adding to config map: [Group]  /Channel/Application/Org1MSP
2018-07-30 07:54:34.989 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 0cb Adding to config map: [Value]  /Channel/Consortium
2018-07-30 07:54:34.989 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN 0cc [channel: chainhero] Rejecting broadcast of config message from 172.18.0.1:35764 because of error: error authorizing update: error validating ReadSet: existing config does not contain element for [Group]  /Channel/Application but was in the read set
2018-07-30 07:54:34.989 UTC [orderer/common/server] func1 -> DEBU 0cd Closing Broadcast stream
```

There is no previous warning or error.

### configtx.yaml

```
---
Organizations:

    - &OrdererOrg
        Name: OrdererMSP
        ID: OrdererMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/hf.chainhero.io/msp
        Policies: &OrdererOrgPolicies
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"
    - &Org1
        Name: Org1MSP
        ID: Org1MSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.hf.chainhero.io/msp
        Policies: &Org1Policies
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin')"
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.org1.hf.chainhero.io
              Port: 7051

Capabilities:
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        V1_1: true
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        V1_1: true
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        V1_2: true
        V1_1: false

Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    ACLs: &ACLsDefault
        lscc/ChaincodeExists: /Channel/Application/Readers
        lscc/GetDeploymentSpec: /Channel/Application/Readers
        lscc/GetChaincodeData: /Channel/Application/Readers
        lscc/GetInstantiatedChaincodes: /Channel/Application/Readers
        qscc/GetChainInfo: /Channel/Application/Readers
        qscc/GetBlockByNumber: /Channel/Application/Readers
        qscc/GetBlockByHash: /Channel/Application/Readers
        qscc/GetTransactionByID: /Channel/Application/Readers
        qscc/GetBlockByTxID: /Channel/Application/Readers
        cscc/GetConfigBlock: /Channel/Application/Readers
        cscc/GetConfigTree: /Channel/Application/Readers
        cscc/SimulateConfigTreeUpdate: /Channel/Application/Readers
        peer/Propose: /Channel/Application/Writers
        peer/ChaincodeToChaincode: /Channel/Application/Readers
        event/Block: /Channel/Application/Readers
        event/FilteredBlock: /Channel/Application/Readers

    Organizations:

    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        Org1MemberPolicy:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.member')"

    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
    OrdererType: solo
    Addresses:
        - orderer.hf.chainhero.io:7050
    BatchTimeout: 2s
    BatchSize:
        MaxMessageCount: 10
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 98 MB
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB
    MaxChannels: 0
    Kafka:
        Brokers:

    Organizations:

    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"

    Capabilities:
        <<: *OrdererCapabilities

Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities

Profiles:

    OrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - <<: *OrdererOrg
                  Policies:
                      <<: *OrdererOrgPolicies
                      Admins:
                          Type: Signature
                          Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - <<: *Org1
                      Policies:
                          <<: *Org1Policies
                          Admins:
                              Type: Signature
                              Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.member')"

    Channel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to pass this error by changing the name of the generated channel. However, this does not explain why some names do not work.

Comment: Could you explain it better please

Comment: Using `configtxgen` with the channel named `chainhero`, this fails. But with another name, like `mychannel`, it works.

Comment: i think you are running into the problem described here: https://github.com/bft-smart/fabric-orderingservice/issues/8#issuecomment-364271529 basically the channel id when creating genesis block has to be different from the channel id when creating channel.tx. also fyi the channel id cannot have underscores. i tried underscore and got error with fabric v1.3

Answer (score 7):

I got the solution from [JSKIM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5479219/jskim). Since you are using the fabric v1.2, the orderer will create a default channel when the orderer node started up with the genesis block.

I guess you are using `configtxgen` to generate your own channel artifacts but ignore the naming rules of the channel. So when your `exec` into your orderer's container:

`docker exec -it <orderer's container ID> bash`

and `cd` into the `chains` directory, which is set to `/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/chains` by default. You will notice that there is already a channel exits.

Here is the solution:

```
configtxgen -profile testOrgsOrdererGenesis -channelID testchannel -outputBlock ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/orderer.block
configtxgen -profile testorgschannel -channelID mychannel-outputCreateChannelTx ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/mychannel.tx
```

when you generate the genesis block, using channelID to specific it. Or you can rename your channel when your create channel configuration transaction.

Comment: should both the above commands be run instead of the ones in the documentation?
I have the same issue.. Heres my link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60550788/bad-request-error-validating-channel-creation-transaction-for-new-channel-in