# BAD_REQUEST -- error validating channel creation transaction for new channel in the Hyperledger Tutorial

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

i get an error for hyperledger fabric.
I followed the documentation and I came across his error when I ran the below command

```
peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

the error being

> BAD_REQUEST -- error validating channel creation transaction for new channel 'fyp', could not succesfully apply update to template configuration: error authorizing update: error validating ReadSet: existing config does not contain element for [Group]  /Channel/Application/Org1MSP but was in the read set

Comment: Any update?? @Pamuditha

Comment: @Paradox if you got the same issue, Please check your channel name when generating channel artifacts (the channelID attribute )